# how to set fragment in activity and add cardview in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to build a e-commerce app, now I am stucked here. When try to add fragment class in my activity some errors showing.

1. when I open my fragment recyclerview items bottom margin is too long, its adjusting automatically.
2. when I back to activity fragment class items and activity items all showing
3. when I back a blank page is shown

my codes are below

```
//this is my activity.xml
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this `activity.xml` had a frame layout.i try to add fragment in this frame layout. and i have two fragnent class.fragment one and two
This is my `one_fragment.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/old_order_recycle"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

//two_fragment.xml
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sirajmalayil.sneakers.OrderActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite">
            <TextView
                android:text="no active orders"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="There are no recent orders to show."
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@mipmap/footprints"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_start_shopping"
                android:text="start shopping"
                android:background="@drawable/login_btn"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPink"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_old_orders"
            android:text="show my old orders"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPink"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_colored_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

//this is my two_fragment class
public class two_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView txtStartShoppi,txtoldOrders;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_active_orders,container,false);

        txtStartShoppi = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_start_shopping);
        txtoldOrders = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_old_orders);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("ORDERS");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        clickListeners();



         return rootView;
    }

    private void clickListeners() {
        txtStartShoppi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        txtoldOrders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new OldOrderFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}


//this is my activity class
public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = new ActiveOrdersFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }

}

//this is my one_fragment
public class one_fragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Orders> ordersList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<products> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    OldOrdersAdapter oldOrdersAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_old_orders,container,false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("MY ARCHIVED ORDERS");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        prepareOrderList();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.old_order_recycle);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        oldOrdersAdapter = new OldOrdersAdapter(getActivity(),ordersList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(oldOrdersAdapter);


        return rootView;
    }

    private void prepareOrderList() {
        Orders orders = new Orders("delivered","1245-5566-7890-1123","Placed on Sunday, December, 2017",
                "Rs.750.45","Friday, January 5, 2018");
        ordersList.add(orders);
        orders = new Orders("delivered","1245-5566-7890-1123","Placed on Sunday, December, 2017",
                "Rs.750.45","Friday, January 5, 2018");
        ordersList.add(orders);
        orders = new Orders("delivered","1245-5566-7890-1123","Placed on Sunday, December, 2017",
                "Rs.750.45","Friday, January 5, 2018");
        ordersList.add(orders);
        orders = new Orders("delivered","1245-5566-7890-1123","Placed on Sunday, December, 2017",
                "Rs.750.45","Friday, January 5, 2018");
        ordersList.add(orders);

        //oldOrdersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

//this is my Adapter class
public class OldOrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OldOrdersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private List<Orders> ordersList = new ArrayList<>();


    public OldOrdersAdapter(Context context, List<Orders> ordersList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.ordersList = ordersList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OldOrdersAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_old_orders,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Orders orders = ordersList.get(position);

        holder.orderStatus.setText(orders.getOrder_status());
        holder.orderNo.setText(orders.getOrder_no());
        holder.orderPlacedDate.setText(orders.getOrder_placed_date());
        holder.orderdItemPrice.setText(orders.getOrder_item_price());
        holder.orderDeliverDate.setText(orders.getOrder_delivered_date());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ordersList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView orderStatus,orderNo,orderPlacedDate,orderdItemPrice,orderDeliverDate;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            orderStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_status);
            orderNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_no);
            orderPlacedDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_placed_date);
            orderdItemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_price);
            orderDeliverDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order_item_deliver_date);

        }
    }
}
```

Ok, all codes here.iam new in android . so i dont know whtais the problrm here. some time fragment and activity contents are mixing..
the problems are only in xml file.not in programattic code

Comment: Go step by step, add `fragment` in `activity` and see if it's working fine back and forth then add `recycerview`. It'll help you to solve one problem at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..
set both fragment background color into root attribute it means Relative layout tag.

```
    android:background="@android:color/white"
```

and card view refer this link it give good demo for that..

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

add fragment into activity then call onCreate method in below code..

```
       Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: you suggested cardview and recyclerview,. i need ho t add fragment in activity

Comment: one of the problem is here, my activity have a frameLayout.i added fragment.xml to this frame layout.when i click back button from fragment showing my blank frame layout

Comment: what other problem

Comment: when press back then finshed activity.

Comment: onBackPress method call this                     finish();

Comment: i tried getActivity().onBackPressed();   but its not working. when i pressed back in my fragment classs showing blank white page, then i click again back its  going to previous activity

Comment: then it show main activity layout. because fragment added into stack. if not show then main activity on BackPress method called finished.

Comment: thankyou lot.....i removed addTobackStack(null). now thats fine..the another problem is my cardview to another have very long distance